# Read xml file in c# wpf

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

I have a xml file that i would like to read in a text file. It has to be put out as text (not the code itself). What i have right now: (in a button to open the xml file). I can open the file right now and put it in the textbox, but as expcted, it shows just as code, not showing the calculations i want to see.

```
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNodeList xmlnode;
        int i = 0;
        string str = null;
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            tbBerekeningen.Text = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog.FileName);
        xmldoc.Load(tbBerekeningen.Text);
        xmlnode = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("Product");
        for (i = 0; i <= xmlnode.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText.Trim();
            str = xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText.Trim() + "  " + xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(1).InnerText.Trim() + "  " + xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(2).InnerText.Trim();
            MessageBox.Show(str);
```

xml file is as any other xml file:

elements are

```
<Som>
 <Getal1>1</Getal1>
  <Operator>+</Operator>
 <Getal2>34</Getal2>
</Som>
```

Comment: xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("Product"). Does the XML file have a element named Product? (the xml that you posted earlier did not contain this element)

Comment: You need to explain better what the issues are.  We don't know what the calculations that you need.

Comment: @Johan i edited the post, and yes, i had not. But even when i put in "Som" it still gives the whole xml code

Comment: @jdweng see edit > xml code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code :

```
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNodeList xmlnode;
        int i = 0;
        string str = null;
        string result = string.Empty;
        List<int> Value1 = new List<int>();
        List<int> Value2 = new List<int>();
        List<string> Operator = new List<string>();
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {

            xmldoc.Load(openFileDialog.FileName);
            xmlnode = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("Som");
            for (i = 0; i <= xmlnode.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText.Trim();
                str = str + xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText.Trim() + "  " + xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(1).InnerText.Trim() + "  " + xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(2).InnerText.Trim() + System.Environment.NewLine;
                Value1.Add(int.Parse(xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText.Trim()));
                Value2.Add(int.Parse(xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(2).InnerText.Trim()));
                Operator.Add(xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(1).InnerText.Trim());
            }
            tbBerekeningen.Text = str;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < Value1.Count; j++)
        {
            if (Operator[j] == "+")
            {
                result = result + Value1[j] + Value2[j] + System.Environment.NewLine;
            }

            //add if else block or switch cases for all the operators.
            //e.g if (Operator[j] == "-")

        }

        tbBerekeningen.Text = result;
```

You can see all your calculations in MessageBox as for loop progresses.

Comment: Well, it works, so thanks, but is there any way to show the calculations in "tbCalculations"(not in messagebox)?

Comment: Edited my code sample. It will now show all calculations in "tbCalculations".

Comment: Awesome! just as expected! Just an extra: How could i make it calculate the numbers?

Comment: @user6840583 See edited sample, it will show calculation in "tbCalculations"